# Multiple select not updating when value changed through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select where each option has a class set to it.
 Depending on the class i can pre-select all options with a specific class so the user doesn't have to select them all by himself. 
So far it works fine, till to the point where i manually select one option by clicking on it. From this point on the pre-selects seem to don't work anymore. BUT only the visuals don't work anymore, the options still get the 'selected="selected"' applied to them. Also .val() on the select returns all values selected by the pre-selector. So in the background everything works fine, but the user can't see that it worked.

Here's my select:

```
<select class="form-control d-block w-100 col-8 col-xl-12" id="brand-select" name="brands" size="15" multiple>
    <c:forEach var="brand" items="${brands}">
        <option class='<c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${brand.isCompanyBrand()}">COMPANYBRAND</c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>FOREIGNBRAND</c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>' value="${brand.brandCode}">${brand.description}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And here's one of the selectors:

```
selectCompanyBrands.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    $("#brand-select option").attr("selected", false)
    $("#brand-select option.COMPANYBRAND").attr("selected", true);
}, false);
```

I'm currently out of ideas what i can do to resolve this problem.

Comment: try `prop` instead of  `attr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through this in jquery [`doc`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and I quote for specificity:

> Attributes vs. Properties
>
> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

Jquery, or rather its later versions, clearly distinguishes between *attributes* and *properties*. So the simple rule is that if you want to set a *property* (something that is related to a user action like a form element) use `#prop()` and otherwise use `#attr()`.

Here you should be using `#prop` like this:

```
selectCompanyBrands.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $("#brand-select option").prop("selected", false)
    $("#brand-select option.COMPANYBRAND").prop("selected", true);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with prop. I knew it would be something simple. Well i won't make this mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample working code to help you. I have used [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option").prop("selected", false)
  $('select option.someclass').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size="15">
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="newclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="newclass">some option</option>
<option class="newclass">some option</option>
<option class="newclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
<option class="someclass">some option</option>
</select>
```