# jquery prev and next in slideshow in order repeatedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slideshow

I would like to ask why the following code cannot go through 1,2,3,1,2,3 in order ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hTgv3/1/))
while I continue to press "next".

When I open and run the following code in Chrome it fails to run the code in order with "1,2,3" (it stops at 3).

**HTML**

```
<div id="slides">
   <ul class="options-list">
   <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-73" name="bundle_option"checked="checked" value="73"></li>
   <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-72" name="bundle_option" value="72"></li>
   <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-74" name="bundle_option" value="74"></li>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
   <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
   <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    var $all     = $('.getradiotomove');
    var $current = $('.getradiotomove:checked');

    var index = $all.index($current) + 1;
    if(index >= $all.length)
        index = 0;
    $($all[index]).attr('checked', 'checked');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The sample works for me on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: ... i cannot make it in firefox and chrome. Why

Comment: did you check the error log?

Comment: no error.. .....

Comment: Check the debugger and step through the code one by one

Comment: @taikachan .Clear cache & try again. Or open in incognito mode in Chrome browser.

Comment: i know... the problem... only jquery library 1.6.3 support this. Other update jquery library cannot support this script. But anything wrong with this script??  it sounds anything happend properly.

Comment: its possibly because of using `#attr()` - use `#prop()` instead - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611494/multiple-select-not-updating-when-value-changed-through-javascript-jquery/45611737#45611737)... I'm going to mark as duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple select not updating when value changed through javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611494/multiple-select-not-updating-when-value-changed-through-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with one more approach http://jsfiddle.net/hTgv3/162/

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
    if($('.getradiotomove:checked').parent().is(':last-child')){
     $('ul[class="options-list"] > li')
       .first()
        .find('.getradiotomove')
       .prop('checked', true);
    } else {
     $('.getradiotomove:checked')
        .parent()
        .next('li')
        .find('.getradiotomove')
        .prop('checked', true);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slides">
    <ul class="options-list">
        <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-73" name="bundle_option" value="73" checked></li>
        <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-72" name="bundle_option" value="72"></li>
        <li><input type="radio" class="getradiotomove" id="bundle-74" name="bundle_option" value="74"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome @taikachan :)

Comment: it works in the plain html files. however, if i put in my website (with a lot of plugin), it cannot make it continously.    However, your solution is the the best for me.

Comment: Let's try to debug you issue. Can you check what error you are getting in browser console?

Comment: Have you used **". getradiotomove"** class anywhere else other than this particular input checkbox??

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it. Updated code `$('ul[class="options-list"] > li')`