# Jquery .attr() sets value as undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email Visible (Fill other means of contact to change)</label>
                    <select id="emailVisible" required name="emailVisible" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="yes" selected = "selected">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

setInterval(function(){
            console.log("GOOO");
            if ($("#twitterInput").val() == "" && $("#facebookInput").val() == "" && $("#steamInput").val() == "") {
                console.log("1");
                $("#emailVisible").attr("disabled","disabled");
            } else {
                console.log("2");
                $("#emailVisible").attr("disabled",false);
                console.log($('#emailVisible').attr('disabled'));
            }                   
        }, 1000);
```

> "console.log($('#emailVisible').attr('disabled'));" prints undefined
>   in the console.

"2" is printed every second.

I do not know what is incorrect in my syntax.

Comment: Why the downvote ? If you downvote, please say why...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple select not updating when value changed through javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611494/multiple-select-not-updating-when-value-changed-through-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`prop()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinhLfeiePVAhUMro8KHYRKBPoQFgiIATAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprop%2F&usg=AFQjCNHaMBB-3221pUloi4_sHJpwg7mWnA) instead of `attr()` .And change the value with boolean type not with `string` .And dont forget to add 3 input

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#twitterInput").val() == "" && $("#facebookInput").val() == "" && $("#steamInput").val() == "") {
    console.log("1");
    $("#emailVisible").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    console.log("2");
    $("#emailVisible").prop("disabled", false);
    console.log($('#emailVisible').prop('disabled'));
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="twitterInput">
<input id="facebookInput">
<input id="steamInput">
  <label>Email Visible (Fill other means of contact to change)</label>
  <select id="emailVisible" required name="emailVisible" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="yes" selected = "selected">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Bingo. Thx ^^ that was it

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that there will be no `disabled` attribute in `<select>` with `id="emailVisible` when you execute the jquery

```
 $("#emailVisible").attr("disabled",false);
```

This is because it removes this attribute to make the selectbox enable. That is why when you access `$('#emailVisible').attr('disabled')` it is `undefined` as there is no such attribute. You can verify yourself by using `inspect element` on this selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
            console.log("GOOO");
            if ($("#twitterInput").val() == "" && $("#facebookInput").val() == "" && $("#steamInput").val() == "") {
                console.log("1");
                $("#emailVisible").prop("disabled","disabled");
            } else {
                console.log("2");
                $("#emailVisible").prop("disabled",false);
                console.log($('#emailVisible').prop('disabled'));
            }                   
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email Visible (Fill other means of contact to change)</label>
                    <select id="emailVisible" required name="emailVisible" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="yes" selected = "selected">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Just change the attr to prop as disable is a property.